# Devise send_reset_password_instructions does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I'm adding a function in my controller, the only goal is to trigger the forgot password procedure through API Request.

Here is the `reset_password` method-

```
  def reset_password
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    @user.send_reset_password_instructions
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml  { render :xml => user_api_ressource(@user, :xml)}
      format.json  { render :json => user_api_ressource(@user, :json)}
    end
  end
```

I'm receiving the mail with the reset password link, it opens the page where I can set a new password but when I submit the form it says that the token is invalid.

I'm using sendgrid to send email. I think it's not a token truncate problem.

I'm running the rails application on Heroku cedar with the latest version of devise.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue. In my case, it was because the `user` was `unscoped`. It seems like it doesn't the user is not found in that case.

It is in the Devise sources in [/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/6b3b0c5e8c57253d3d178def678ccc26e66cd630/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb) at line 113

```
      recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:reset_password_token, reset_password_token)
```

which do not search `unscoped`.

I'll fork the repo, let me know if you are interested too.